# How to get selected option in Google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, html-select

I want to access the value of selected option in Google Script.

I got this HTML form. There is a option.

```
  <form id="invoice" _lpchecked="1">
    <label for="company">company:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="company" name="company" value=""><br>
    <br>
    <label for="user">created:</label>
    <select id="user">
       <option value="Radek">Radek</option>
       <option value="Lucka">Lucka</option>
     </select>         
    <input type="submit" value="send" onclick="event.preventDefault(); sendForm(this);">
  </form>
```

The form is sent to Google Script

```
  function sendForm(theForm){
    //var invoice = document.getElementById("invoice");
    //invoice.user = document.getElementById("user").value;
    
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(formSent)
                     .processForm(document.getElementById("invoice"));
  }
```

And then in GAS I can access the form data. By logging the form data I found out the the option does not have a key. In the `form` object there is the correct value but with an empty key. Could help to get the select option in GAS? I tried to add the `user` key to the form data but it did not work.

```
function processForm(form){
  var result = "OK";
  var data = [(new Date()).toLocaleString("cs-CZ"),
             form.company,
             form.user]
  for (var key in form) {
    Logger.log('the key is: ' + key);
    Logger.log('the value is: ' + form[key]);
  };
  saveInvoiceData(data); // saves data to Google Sheets

  return result;
}
```

Is there a way to debug this in IDE, using breakpoints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the reason of your issue is that `name` attribute is not used at `<select id="user">`. So please modify it as follows.

#### From:

```
<select id="user">
```

#### To:

```
<select id="user" name="user">
```

#### Note:

- When you use the script as the Web Apps, when the script is modified, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.
- About the debug in this situation, unfortunately, in this case, I think that the debug at the script editor cannot be directly used. So for example, how about using the following script?

  ```
    function processForm(form){
      SpreadsheetApp.openById("###").appendRow([JSON.stringify(form)]);
      return "ok";
    }
  ```

  - Using this script, when the form is submitted, the value of `form` can be confirmed. By this, it can be found that using the Spreadsheet, your current script returns the object of `{"":"###","company":"###"}` without the key.

Comment: you were right it was the missing `name`. Regarding the debugging ... of course I am saving the form data to the spreadsheet but I was after debugging the data in between it is sent to the web and before it was saved. I used Logger but was wondering if there was any other way.

Comment: @Radek Thank you for replying. For example, when you are using Web Apps, is this information useful for your situation? https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#checklog